# PhP 5.2.17 not detecting MSSQL 2000

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm currently using IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2... I've got it setup to run PhP (5.2.17 AND 5.3), and at some point I had MySQL 5.5 too...

Now the thing is, I've changed the backend DB and altered the PhP codes to work with MSSQL 2000 (RTM), the problem is, IIS can establish a connection string to a particular DB inside the DB Server, but PhP doesn't wanna see the MSSQL server. There's no mention of it in the PhPinfo report...

I've done the basics, uncomment the required in PhP.ini, configured IIS to process PhP, etc.

But I can't get PhP to work with MSSQL 2000 for the love of me... Any ideas?

Comment: PHP.  All caps.  PHP can not automatically detect the presence of a database.  Are you looking for a specific *driver*?

Comment: Lol, Apologies for the lack of capitalization mate. I figured it out, there's a small bit of change required in the PHP.ini file that I had overlooked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small bit of code that needs to be uncommented in the PHP.ini file... I made a mistake by misconfiguring the file... When I did take the sweet time to reformat and reinstall everything, I realized that I had forgotten to uncomment the line which allows PHP to see the MSSQL driver...