# PHP 5.2.17 not detecting Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, iis

- using IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I need to get SQL and MySql connection in the same server.

So i started getting IIS7 and installing PHP5.3, it went all fine with MySql, but i couldn't make use of Mssql, so sql wansn't working. (PHP 5.3 don't handle mssql)

So i changed to PHP 5.2.17 (the one I already have on one server that works with mssql)

And all went fine with mssql so I can connectto Sql now. but MySql stoped working...

I go to info.php and it shows mysqli enabled..

I think is very similar to
[PhP 5.2.17 not detecting MSSQL 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306599/php-5-2-17-not-detecting-mssql-2000)
but i still don't get it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning on running PHP on Windows with IIS, I *strongly* recommend installing it via Microsoft's [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). This should set up everything you need, including SQL Server support. I'm fairly certain that it ships with a MySQL driver as well, though I've never used that.

This will also give you a module in your IIS configuration panel for PHP configuration, which is handy. You may have to tweak a few settings to get everything enabled, but it's basically an interface on top of `php.ini`, so if you're comfortable there you should have no trouble.

Comment: Ok thanks, ill give it a try! But the SQL is on another server, just like the mysql... i just dont undestand why php5.3 can see Mysql and php5.2 cant. I have one php5.2 with mysql.. so i know it works!